# How build a query using typed parameters?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM for query like this.

```
userRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("user")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("user.profile")
    .where("user.profile.reputation > :r" , {r:10})
    .getMany();
```

it really bothers me because I dont like strings as identifier on my code. For instance, for some reason we decide to rename `reputation` to `rate` It will replace every typed definitions but these queries.

I also notice that `QueryBuilder` accepts other parameters than string

```
where(where: Brackets | string | ((qb: this) => string) | ObjectLiteral | ObjectLiteral[], parameters?: ObjectLiteral): this;
```

How can I define a typed query using QueryBuilder?